# Search for a Word in an Array of strings & give its position using Binary Search Technique

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, binary-search

The question is to **search for a word and give its position using Binary Search Technique.** I am accepting all the words in the array and then sorting them using *Arrays.sort*. Then I use the *binarySearch()* function to search for a user accepted word but the word's position is not showing correctly. 
It's giving random outputs and I can't understand why! there might me something wrong with the way i wrote my for-loop!
**I have attached a output screen with multiple outputs.**

[image: output screen]

If anybody could help me that'd be great! Thanks :)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch10
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int i;  

   System.out.println("Enter number of words you wish to input: ");
   int n=sc.nextInt();

   String[] words= new String[n];

   System.out.println("Enter the words");
   for ( i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
   {
       System.out.print("WORD " + (i + 1) + ": ");
       words[i] = sc.next();
   }

   System.out.println("enter the word you want to search for");
   String word=sc.next();

   Arrays.sort(words);


   int index= Arrays.binarySearch(words,word);
   System.out.println(word+ "="+ index);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output seems to be correct, according to the attached image. After sorting the array alphabetically (using `Array.sort()`), the order of the elements will be:
are, hello, how, you.
The index of "you" is 3, as in the output. Same for the second example, where the index of "are" is 0.

Comment: maybe printing all the words after the array is sorted would help?

Comment: Sure it would. You can also add the index 

...
Arrays.sort(words);

for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
      System.out.println(i+": "+words[i])
}
...

Comment: aha! it worked! thanks a lot :) its a simple workaround! Never thought of it!! I wanted another help if you wouldn't mind! instead of just accepting one word if I wanted to accept bigger strings then what changes I would have to make?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "accept bigger strings"

Comment: like searching for bigger strings rather than just a word: 1. hello how are you 2. is your name Waddah 3. i wanted to meet you ...is it confusing i am sorry! i am a noob in java

Comment: If you want to search for the full sentence ("hello how are you"), then you don't need to change anything. Note that the code is case sensitive.
However if you want to search for all sentences that contain a specific word (like "you"), you need to create a custom function instead of Arrays.binarySearch. For example:
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   if(words[i].contains(word)){
     indexes.add(i);
   }
}
if(indexes.isEmpty()) System.out.println("word not found");
else
System.out.println("Indexes: "+indexes);

Answer (score 0):

You are getting random values because you are sorting the array first,

After sorting the indexes are changed

Comment: ok thanks! I will remove it, is there something I can do to correct my output. there was a little bug that was preventing the output screen link to display. you might wanna check that out!

Answer (score 0):

Because `Arrays.sort` is an in-place sorting. It means that when you sort the words, their positions have been changed: the new order will be the lexicographical (alphabetical) order. Here's an example:

```
// before the sort
// words = ["word-b", "word-c", "word-a"]

Arrays.sort(words);

// after the sort
// words = ["word-a", "word-b", "word-c"]
```

As you see, word `word-c` has changed its position from index 1 to index 2.

### Solution 1

A simple solution is to avoid using sort and binary search here. You can find the word using a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (searchWord.equals(words[i])) {
        // word found at index i
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

If you want to continue your work using sort, you need to use a `Map` to store the initial position (index) of each word: the key of the map is the word, the value of the map is the word initial index.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i wish i could use that! its much more simpler & also i have practiced it before but my project asks to use Binary Search Technique! i will somehow try to do it!

Comment: @user58736 I added the 2nd solution, and I wish that can help you.